# Aura Component not filling all the fields in Quick Action

Tags: aura, quickaction, component

I'm trying to configure a quick Send Email action in Aura, some of the fields are okay but some just won't prepopulate...

```
var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
var fields = {//WhoId: {value: contactRecord.Id},
                EmailTemplateId: {value: "00Xb0000000Z5CVEA0"}, 
                RelatedToId: {value: accountRecord.Id},
                Subject: {value: "Mifid"},
                HtmlBody: {value: "Mifid", insertType: "cursor"},
                CcAddress: {value: contactRecord.Owner.Email + (userRecord.Manager ? ";"+userRecord.Manager.Email : "")}
            };
var args = { actionName: "SendEmail" , targetFields: fields};
actionAPI.setActionFieldValues(args);
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

Subject, Body, CcAddress are all filled up correctly, but the email template isn't and the related lookup either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not supported. There is an open Idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015JBQQA2) and a confirmation from SF that you cannot add predefined template in quick action. [See here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8bdQAC)

> Predefined email templates is not yet supported. The Template field was added to support Classic Email Templates and should not be used to predefine templates.

Also looking at fields for this actions, I see that `EmailTemplateId` is a lookup field

`{"fieldName":"EmailTemplateId","type":"placeholderLookup"}`

Trying this by passing an object results in an error

```
var fields = {
    EmailTemplate: {Id: "00X1l000000hc5vEAA"}, 
            
    CcAddress: {value: "myemail@domain.com"}
};
```

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer ! Do you have any idea as to why the other field doesn't work ? (the RelatedToId field), it's also a lookup...